# In python how to load a pipe delimited file into csv file after a occurrence of a text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, csv

I have a file which goes something like this:

```
Date: 05/20/2020

Age: 25 

Gender: male 

Convert to csv:

Apples|7|monday|texas             

Oranges|9|thursday|california 

Peaches|12|Monday|kansas 

Mangos|17|friday|illinois
```

And I need to convert the partial file into CSV after the text ‘convert to csv’. Last four lines where pipe delimited is needed to be loaded into csv file using python script. Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
import csv

with open(filename) as infile:
    for _ in range(4):
        next(infile)    # Skip first 4 lines
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter="|")
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

**Output:**

```
['Apples', '7', 'monday', 'texas']
['Oranges', '9', 'thursday', 'california']
['Peaches', '12', 'Monday', 'kansas']
['Mangos', '17', 'friday', 'illinois']
```

---

Edit as per comment. Using `str.startswith('Convert to csv')`

```
import csv

with open(filename) as infile:
    line = next(infile).strip()
    while not line.startswith('Convert to csv'):
        line = next(infile).strip()
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter="|")
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: Not everytime I get that line in number 4 line. That is the problem

Answer (score 0):

I find the table by looking for the "Convert to csv:" line, and then use `io` to read into `pandas`:

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

# load the text
path = 'file.txt'

with open(path, 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

# remove empty lines and find the table
lines = [line.strip() for line in lines if line.strip()]
start = lines.index('Convert to csv:')
data = '\n'.join(lines[start+1:])

# load into pandas
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='|', header=None)
```

Result:

```
         0   1         2           3
0   Apples   7    monday       texas
1  Oranges   9  thursday  california
2  Peaches  12    Monday      kansas
3   Mangos  17    friday    illinois
```

---

Other thought was to just explicitly look for lines containing the pipe `"|"`; you could combine this with looking for the start of the table as well:

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

# load the text
path = 'file.txt'
with open(path, 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

# now just check for lines with the pipe
lines = [line.strip() for line in lines if '|' in line]
data = '\n'.join(lines)

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='|', header=None)
```